# Помогите разобраться с GitHub

Tags: github

Я очень туго располагаюсь в новой среде, и вообще в чем либо. Понимаю что нужно начинать работать в GitHub. Но только пытаюсь что-то узнать, и тут же все путается. Прошу написать ответ, как человеку который сегодня узнал что есть сервис для open source проектов как GitHub. Хотел бы найти ссылки на хорошие документации или статьи, которые помогли бы мне в моей проблеме.

Comment: а что конкретно интересует?

Comment: Учебников по Git много, по GitHub информации тоже хватает, пробовали искать и читать что-нибудь?

Comment: @Alexandr хотел-бы узнать о том как добавлять туда свои проекты и работать в паре с кем либо. И как работать, читать и изучать чужие проекты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Существует довольно большое число качественных материалов и туториалов по работе с Git и сервисом GitHub. Возможно, это не в правилах ответа, но тут лучше всего помочь такими материалами. Начать, возможно, стоит с самого Git, а потом уже по работе с сервисом, когда будет общее представление о работе с системой контроля версий.

По самым базовым командам Git и воркфлоу можно ознакомиться по ссылкам ниже: http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/

https://githowto.com/ru

А здесь непосредственно по сервису: http://try.github.io/

Также есть фундаментальная книга Git Pro https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2
но для первого знакомства с Git можно перейти по первым двум ссылкам